# MSAL configuration in info.plist with msauth.<app_bundle_id> open the Microsoft authenticator app to authenticate the username

Tags: ios, authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

I'm developing an iOS application that works for B2B and other businesses, and users can log in through SSO using MSAL. To configure the application, we need to add the client ID to the info.plist file, which means that when a new business comes onboard, we need to update the info.plist file with the new client ID and release a new version of the app on the App Store.

To avoid this problem, I modified the CFBundleURLSchemes key in the info.plist file by adding msauth.<app_bundle_id> to support dynamic client IDs. This solution works fine for all dynamic client IDs, except when the user has the Microsoft Authenticator app installed on their iPhone. In this case, the app opens the Authenticator app instead of the WKWebView. After authentication in the Authenticator app, it does not provide an access token, and the callback method openURL:(NSURL *)url options is called with a URL that looks like this:

msauth.com.<app_bundle_id>://auth/broker?msg_protocol_ver=3&response=KG5qTOOVgQGuChzrzDKb3_6ZL_xubgdFpz-roV_asaSLv8R9LG0Kw5U44QNhYFmSSN87GTGkrAsaE0M49aYdaLNxqNsLXu9c91fumZyBJWJzsvQhYJY-O97iN5FWooEMHbHE9OrXqzbLaYWy0tiscp7y5XjePlUZODoT6Ye9lNTbRR43Q5x4Bl8tJSFi6079DIJs3bCxrNdlMEs4qst_jfCzHo0cpmzgIWqxabh_FzOduNDbAaIfa0FxFchhJNshDMQ0xd8uduYU45PeesXLDTn9jvc3RPNK7rMDwOrzhFoZ0Pvc2K44VfcbMaEiXJRj6l0iOonzrnG0hJ0dX6x-iKpA0i2QlH9WNqeFN2zhssG-RkcAT2p6eybP7R5JpKEYQVed.......

How can I prevent the Microsoft Authenticator app from being opened in this scenario?

Comment: Have you added the [required code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-macos-ios) into your AppDelegate/scene delegate? You do not want to prevent Microsoft Authenticator from opening. It provides a simpler SSO experience, and may be required by an organisation's conditional access policies.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to prevent the Microsoft Authenticator app to be opened.

```
MSALGlobalConfig.brokerAvailability = .none
```